# How to close Google App Engine URL's for direct access after creating load balancer's

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall, gcp-load-balancer

I have created a load balancer on my Google Cloud app engine, and also have added SSL certificates to them, but the links of the App Engines are still active and don't have any security on them.

So I wanted to know how can I close or disable those links of the app engine?

And secondly,

Can we do something like only the load balancer is able to access the App Engine and the load balancer is open to public and the app engine links are closed for the public access.

Something like if the load balancer had a static IP we could have added it to the App engine firewall and allowed that IP and denied the rest?

Please Help me with this scenario.

Comment: `The IP address of the Google Front End (GFE) that connected to the backend. These IP addresses are in the 130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16 ranges.`  https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#:~:text=The%20IP%20address%20of%20the,0.0%2F16%20ranges.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the ingress for App Engine so requests sent to the default URL are discarded and only the Load Balancer will be capable to communicate with the backend service.

To do so, you can modify the [ingress controls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/application-security#ingress_controls) and set it to `Internal and Cloud Load Balancing`, so your app will only receive requests that are routed through Cloud Load Balancing, or that are sent from VPC networks in the same project. All other requests will be denied with a 403 error.

I think also this [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-routed#load_balancer) from the documentation on how requests are routed with Cloud Balancing is worth a read for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

- In your GCP cloud console, go to App Engine > Firewall rules.
- Click on Create rule and allow ingress from the LoadBalancer's public IP ranges `130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16 ranges`.

[for reference](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#:%7E:text=The%20IP%20address%20of%20the,0.0%2F16%20ranges)